# Product topology

Tags: general-topology

True or False: There can not exist topologies $\tau, \tau^{'}$ on an infinite set $X$ such that the product topology for $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau^{'})$ coincides with the cofinite topology on $X\times X$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $U$ is open in $τ$, then $U × X$ is open in the product. When is it cofinite?

Comment: $X\times X\setminus U\times X$ should be finite.

Comment: @SucharitaDeb: What does it mean for $U$ given the assumptions?

Comment: $U$ should be $X$ itself in this case, otherwise this won't happen. Am I right?

Comment: @SucharitaDeb: Yes, you're right. So what does that mean for $τ$ and by the same argument for $τ'$? And what is the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau')$ are the trivial topology then they coincide with the cofinite topology on $X\times X$